# how to write data to a json file

Tags: php, extjs

I have data that is coming from a form that should be submitted to a database. I need to know how I can  write this same information I have submitted in my Ajax request to a file. I have a json writer attached to my store. Basically I just need to flush this data into a file. The database is on the server side, this would be a server side operation. How can I do this?

Here is the store

```
Ext.define('ClientInfo.store.LicenseStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'ClientInfo.model.LicenseModel',
    'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
    'Ext.data.reader.Json',
    'Ext.data.writer.Json'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'LicenseStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'ClientInfo.model.LicenseModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            extraParams: {
                class: 'License',
                method: 'get'
            },
            url: 'system/index.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'topics'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                writeAllFields: true,
                encode: true,
                rootProperty: 'topics'
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}

});
```

and here is current ajax request

```
    var productstore = Ext.getStore('ProductStore');
var win = Ext.create ('Ext.window.Window' , {
    title: 'License' ,
    id: 'addLicenseWindow',
    width: 500 ,
    modal: true,
    height: 300 ,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    modelValidation: true,
                    title: 'Licence',
                    items: [

                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            anchor: '100%',
                            id: 'licensenumberTextField',
                            fieldLabel: 'Licence Number',
                            labelWidth: 140,
                            emptyText: 'Licence Number',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            blankText: 'This Field is required',
                            msgTarget: 'under',
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'datefield',
                            anchor: '100%',
                            id: 'startdateTextField',
                            fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
                            labelWidth: 140,
                            allowBlank: false,
                            blankText: 'This Field is required',
                            msgTarget: 'under'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'datefield',
                            anchor: '100%',
                            id: 'enddateTextField',
                            fieldLabel: 'End Date',
                            labelWidth: 140,
                            allowBlank: false,
                            blankText: 'This Field is required',
                            msgTarget: 'under'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'numberfield',
                            anchor: '100%',
                            id: 'durationTextField',
                            fieldLabel: 'Duration',
                            labelWidth: 140,
                            emptyText: 'Duration',
                            allowBlank: false,
                            blankText: 'This Field is required',
                            msgTarget: 'under'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'datefield',
                            anchor: '100%',
                            id: 'expirydateTextField',
                            fieldLabel: 'Expiry Date',
                            labelWidth: 140,
                            allowBlank: false,
                            blankText: 'This Field is required',
                            msgTarget: 'under'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            fieldLabel: 'Product',
                            id: 'productidTextField',
                            valueField: 'product_id',
                            displayField: 'product_name',
                            store: productstore,
                            typeAhead: true,
                            queryMode: 'local',
                            minChars: 2,
                            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'combobox',
                            fieldLabel: 'Company',
                            id: 'companyidtf',
                            valueField: 'company_id',
                            displayField: 'name',
                            store: 'CompanyStore',
                            typeAhead: true,
                            queryMode: 'local',
                            minChars: 2,
                            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
                        }


                    ]
                }
            ],
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            id: 'cancelLicenceBtn',
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            listeners: {
                                click: function(c){
                                    Ext.getCmp('addLicenseWindow').close();
                                }

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'tbspacer',
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            formBind: true,
                            id: 'saveLicenceBtn',
                            text: 'Save',
                            listeners: {
                                click: function(c){
                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                        url: 'system/index.php',
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        params: {
                                            class: 'License',
                                            method: 'add',
                                            data: Ext.encode({
                                            license_number: Ext.getCmp('licensenumberTextField').getValue(),
                                            start_date: Ext.getCmp('startdateTextField').getValue(),
                                            end_date: Ext.getCmp('enddateTextField').getValue(),
                                            duration: Ext.getCmp('durationTextField').getValue(),
                                            expiry_date: Ext.getCmp('expirydateTextField').getValue(),
                                            product_id: Ext.getCmp('productidTextField').getValue(),
                                            company_id: Ext.getCmp('companyidtf').getValue()
                                        })

                                    },
                                                     success: function( response ){
                                        Ext.MessageBox.alert( 'Status', 'Record has been added.' );
                                        Ext.getStore('LicenseStore').reload();
                                        Ext.getStore('LicenseAllStore').reload();
                                        Ext.getCmp( 'addLicenseWindow' ).close();
                                    },
                                        failure: function(){
                                            Ext.MessageBox.alert( 'Status', 'Failed to add record.' );
                                        }
                                });

                            }
                        }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

win.show ();
```

Comment: I am basically adding data to a database and at the same time writing a file to represent the record. That file needs to be json file

Comment: Is it possible to just write to a file with php file_put_contents

Comment: I'll upload my php code to show how I can do it possibly

Comment: Since you use an Ext.form.Panel you can use the "url" config of the form to handle the ajax part, instead of creating an Ext.Ajax.request yourself.

Comment: after adding the url config what would I put into the submit/save button, i.e the button with the ajax request

Comment: you have to call the 'submit' method on the form. There is some examples on forms on the extJS website.